# PHP: check if an element belongs to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I know PHP 4 and PHP 5 supports a built in function `in_array` for determining is an element is in an array or not.

But, I am using a prior version of PHP for some reason and wanted to know what is the alternative for it.

Comment: Are you using PHP 3.xx?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Well, there could be a solution with strpos but it is only build-in since PHP 4

Comment: You are using a version of PHP that is older than Google...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom function. For future compatibility, you could use [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check if the current version of PHP that you're using does indeed have [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
function inArray($needle, $haystack)
{
    if (function_exists('in_array')) {
        return in_array($needle, $haystack);
    } else {
        foreach ($haystack as $e) {
            if ($e === $needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why this way accepted, because if there is no function `in_array`, there also is no loop `foreach`. Both were introduced with the first version of PHP 4. The better answer was given by dev-null-dweller: Check if the function is not available, and only then define it with the same name, and the very basic stuff of pre-millenium PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using something older than PHP 4, `foreach` will also be unavailable, so you will need to stick with `list` and `each`. Also to make in forward compatible, use third parameter for strict comparison:

```
if (!function_exists('in_array')) {
   function in_array($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
       while (list($key, $item) = each($haystack)) {
           if ($strict && $needle === $item) {
               return true;
           } else if (!$strict && $needle == $item) {
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without checking what functions were available in what versions, and comparing against the version you are using (we're not php.net encyclopedia's), your best bet is to go back to basics, and just loop through and check.

```
function in_array($val, $array) {

   foreach($array as $a) {

      if($a === $val)
          return true;

   }

   return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function to mimic the functionality with

```
function my_in_array($ar, $val)
{
  foreach($ar as $k => $v)
  {
    if($v == $val) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

or if you looking for a key

```
function my_in_array($ar, $val)
{
  foreach($ar as $k => $v)
  {
    if($k == $val) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own in array function something like below:

```
function my_in_array($value, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        if ($a == $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```